# Vaadin 7 samples with maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, vaadin

I am new to Vaadin, I would like to find easy to start Vaadin 7 examples with maven(I do not want to download jars manually). I have seen this github repositores, but had problem when trying to build project. [github.com/nfrankel/More-Vaadin](https://github.com/nfrankel/More-Vaadin)

Also are there a official examples from Vaadin.? I use IDEA as a ide.

Thanks.

Comment: Googling "maven vaadin 7" returns this as the first hit for me:
[Vaadin 7 Wiki - Creating a Maven Project](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+a+Maven+project)

Comment: I would like to find examples with GWT integration. But anyway this is  already something to start. Thanks you very much for your help. Please put this comment as an answer and I will accept and upvote your answer.

Comment: What do you mean by GWT integration? GWT is currently part of Vaadin. Do you mean you also want to use traditional GWT components in your Vaadin app? Also, while this isn't a Maven project it might help: http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_Vaadin_Project_with_IntelliJ_IDEA_12

Comment: For integrating GWT components: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating+an+existing+GWT+widget

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find the latest stable version of Vaadin at https://vaadin.com/download. Here you are also given the maven archetype so you can build a quickstart with the latest version, so you just run that command and don't have to download any jars. 
The link to the wiki that Sean Connolly gave you is also good cause it has some starter tips on what to do when you built the archetype.
The following is also a tutorial for integrating GWT widgets: http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-gwt-widgets-vaadin-7